# creating bat file to start multiple applications if not already running - task scheduler

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to set up a task that executes a bat file that will start up a bunch of processes if not already running. I found some examples and tried to put it together but it does not seem like it worked. I would like to set this up on a windows 2008 server and these are all visual studio 2010 vb.net applications.

```
@echo off 
:start
set /p runningprocess="C:\Users...Debug\PROCESS_I.exe"
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq %runningprocess%" | find /I "%runningprocess%" > nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 0 ECHO PROCESS_? is running 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 ECHO PROCESS_? is not running 
pause>nul
goto start 
exit
```

How can I adapt this to run multiple processes:

```
set /p runningprocess="C:\Users...Debug\PROCESS_II.exe"
set /p runningprocess="C:\Users...Debug\PROCESS_III.exe"
```

The task should be able to fire up every 1 or 2 hours to check if processes are already running and if not start new ones. This is my backup plan for making sure my processes will always be running in the event of some failure which I can be alerted by emails from within each application.

Any ideas appreciated.

EDIT: just checked task schedule for last run result and it says "the directory name is invalid"
this is in program/script:

```
"C:\Users\...\BatchProcesses\PTTrackProcesses.bat"
```

and this is in start in

```
C:\Users\...\BatchProcesses\
```

ERROR when running manually

```
C:\Users\..Debug\PROCESS_I.exe
ERROR: The search filter cannot be recognized.
PROCESS is not running
```

Comment: Ok I figured out how to get it to run....the start in entry only needs the path and the quotes need to be removed. But I expected a command window to open and at least to see a confirmation message echoed but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

ok figured it out. Made changes as in comment above and changed the script a little.